# SQL server agent runs SSIS cannot move file to difference server(without domain)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dns, agent

I have a SSIS package, It is implemented to move files between two servers, unfortunately, there is a server is a domain group, the other did not join the domain.

Domain Server is source server, files will be moved from here to other servers. it's has been install SQL Server 2016 and is also running SSIS through SQL Server Agent Job in this server

Another server is destination server, will receive files from source server, it does not install any SQL Server version (Does not join domain).

I can execute package and move file successful manually(Right click SSIS project then click execute) but in SQL Server Agent happened error.

Problem:
After create and setup the proxy account to run SSIS in SQL Server agent job, it's cannot access/move file from source server to destination server.

error message:
"An error occurred with the following error message: "The user name or password is incorrect.  ".

I had tried the below solution:

1. Mapping network drive and use this drive to access
2. Change SQL Server Agent services log on account
3. Add MSDB and set user mapping SQLAgentOperatorRole, SQLAgentReaderRole and SQLAgentUserRole to credentials and mapping to SSIS Package Execution proxy.
4. Set the folder as a shared folder in destination server.
5. Create and save destination server windows credentials in source server.
6. Use destination server's IP address and hostname to tried access move file.

Clarify:

1. Move file use the File System Task in SSIS package.
2. Two server use difference login account (Domain account and local account = administrator)
3. The login account used by the proxy credentials is also a domain user in SQL Server (Source Server)

I've spent a lot of time on the Internet to find, but still did not find a good solution

Comment: you mentioned the shared folder. I think this is the way to go, but did you give full access to everyone? I think using users will be problematic, because the non-domain server will not know about domain users, and the domain server will not know about the  users on the local machine if the SQL Agent is running under the context of a domain account. maybe this will help (https://websiteforstudents.com/create-shares-everyone-full-access-windows-10-server/)

Comment: Hi  Jeremy,  In fact, everyone has been added now, but the same problem still occurs

Comment: any chance of joining this computer to the domain? if not, you could approach the problem with out of the box thinking and a heavy hand. for example, set up an FTP server, then use an ftp task  to transfer the file.